# How to prevent js injection with Laravel 4?

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel, tinymce

I created a contact page where users can add a message. I use `tinymce` for the form.

The problem is where I show all messages. I can't use `{{{ $message->body }}}` because it converts html tags as string. If I use `{{ $message->body }}`, it executes `JavaScript` and it can be dangerous.

I need something to fails the form validation if it contains script tags. So how to do it in Laravel 4? Is there a "laravelic" way to do it?

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. use [**HtmlPurifier**](https://packagist.org/packages/mews/purifier)

Comment: Did `{{ $message->body }}` really execute JavaScript ? because when I write `hello world <script>alert("CSRF");</script>` and view source, `<` and `>` are converted to `&lt;` and `$gt;` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this (Look it here in [User Contributed Notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)):

```
$tagsToStrip = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si'); // you can add more
$message = preg_replace($tagsToStrip, '', $message->body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, all user supplied data should be escaped or purified. To escape the output, you may use the triple curly brace syntax:

Hello, {{{ $name }}}.

http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use an HTML Purifier package for Laravel 4 like https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier

This allows you to specify allowed html tags and attributes (inc css styles) and strips out any unwanted tags (inc ).

You can also use regular input validation on other fields to ensure they're eg alpha only